# Inputs don't line up in firefox/IE, but do in chrome/safari

Tags: html, css

Any idea why this is happening?

http://watch.renmx.com?user=Pri

It is the object in the top right, it looks perfect in chrome, but in firefox it is not lined up.

[image: chrome]

[image: firefox]

Comment: Much, much better if you also post the relevant CSS.

Comment: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and the IE F12 Developer Tools are your friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form > input {

    float: left;
}
```

Add to your CSS

Comment: Every `INPUT` element within a `FORM` in the page should `float: left`?

Comment: As there is only one form on the page, yes.

Comment: Why not suggest something more constructive, like a `class`? Also, can you provide an example?

Comment: @Jared Farrish This answer solves the problem demonstrated in the original post. I need not add any classes or complications to a simple solution.

Comment: Since the OP did not post the source CSS, it's impossible to know if your answer actually works. Also, I'm not sure it's constructive for others to use your answer. I won't downvote (since, I don't know if you're right or wrong, absent any evidence to judge), but I can't upvote either.

Comment: Source CSS in on his website, which is posted in his question.  Implementation of my CSS can be done using "Inspect element" browser tools on the live site.  Furthermore, one can derive whether or not this solution would work without a demonstration, provided they had sufficient knowledge of CSS.

Comment: Like I said, I can see no proof on this page of the answer.

Comment: Soooo... This particular is entirely localized to this question, correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3477/discussion-between-stevether-and-jared-farrish)

Answer (score 0):

Just having a play, probably not the correct way to do this. But I did this

```
.refresh { float: left }
.addshow { 
    border: 0 none;
    color: gray;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 46px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    width: 240px;
}
.btn { float: left }
```

and that seemed to do the trick. Note, I removed the margins as you don't need them on `.addshow` and fiddled with the padding, everything is floated left.