# Putting a button next to an input, for all browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have an input (that holds a number) that I want to put a button next to. This button would, when pressed, increment the value in the box by 1.

I am having a heck of a time lining it up in all browsers though.

I've tried using `button`, `img`, and `a` to accomplish this. `img` does not line up properly in most of the browsers. Meaning that if I put an `input` and an `img` next to each other, the `img` is a few pixels higher than the input, but that varies by browser. The closest i can get is by making it a `button` that is styled with css to use my custom image. It works in Chrome, ie7, and ie10. However, in ie8, ie9, and firefox, it is 1 pixel too high, and I can't for the life of me get them to line up.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424603/inputs-dont-line-up-in-firefox-ie-but-do-in-chrome-safari) that floating would make them line up. Sure enough, it did. But now the input and the button are jammed against the edge of the `td` they're in, and I can't figure out how to move them. Is there perhaps a better method than float? Or just a way to line them up properly?

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/MXg4P/4/) is how it is where I am having issues. In Chrome and ie7, ie10 it works fine. It messes up in ie8,9 and firefox.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/MXg4P/3/) is how it looks with floats. It displays right in all the above browsers, but it is now off-center.

Any suggestions?

Comment: make sure your main holder containing those two fields is having sufficient width to hold those two side by side

Comment: They have more than enough, See the jsfiddle.

Comment: What is your reasoning for using a table?

Comment: the table is actually used for organizing the data on the page, it's a spreadsheet. The last column has this input/button in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a method that fixes my issue, but only for ie8+ which is satisfactory for me.

The structure looks like this:

```
<input class="add_input" type="text" name="qty" value="0" /><a class="add">
    <img src="plus.png"/>
</a>
```

There cannot be a space or new line between the `input` and the `a` or else it will misalign them. The image is simply the "+" by itself, nothing else. Then I use CSS to style the image into the shape I want, with the appropriate `:hover` and `:active` selectors.

Here's the CSS:

```
.add_input{
    width:28px;
    height:18px;
    padding:1px 0;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #0a1c40;
    border-right:0;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.add img{
    background:url(add.png);
    display:inline-block;
    width:18px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid #0b1e45;
    border-radius:0px 12px 12px 0px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.add img:hover {
    background:url(add_hover.png);
}
.add img:active {
    background:url(add_active.png);
}
```

I'm note sure if other `vertical-align` types would work or not, I just know bottom does.

Answer (score 3):

OK. Here is one way. So I think you might like `vertical-align: middle;` It only works on inline and inline block elements aligning them to each other. So it's not aligning them inside a box. I made a little sandbox to test your issues [HERE](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/LHrzj). I'm not sure of your constraints, but I use `box-sizing: border-box;` on most everything these days - So that is something to beware of when looking at the code. I checked it in browser-stack and all seems well for the most part. This is always a difficult task in my experience. I kept to the key points in the CSS below, but there is a bunch of comments and styles and stuff in the codepen. I hope this helps! Good luck!

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <input class="your-input" type="number" /><button class="your-button">+</button>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
* { 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.wrapper {
  float: left;

  height: 4em; /* needs to be defined in this case so that the children know what they should be 100% height of */

  /* just for show */
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5em;
}

.your-input, .your-button {
  display: inline-block;
  /* aligned to each other and not the .wrapper */
  height: 100%;
  /* already was inline by dephault - but just to be clear */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.your-input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20em; /* arbitrary */
  text-indent: 1em;

  border: 1px solid black;
}

.your-button{
  /* whatevers */
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
  width: 6em;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a more indepth look tomorrow, it's getting late here. Does that work in IE7-9? (more importantly 8). I have come up with a solution that works in FF, but throws off ie7 so it leaves ie7-9 out of the equation.

Comment: I used browser-stack to view it in windows xp 7 and 8 - in multiple versions of IE... seemed to work. BUT - I didn't see you note about being locked into a table... so I don't know how that will play out.

Comment: I've messed around with your solution and come across a few things. I can make it work in Chrome, FF, IE10, IE9, but not 8 and 7, or I can make it work in all but FF. The issue is that FF displays borders on-top of the height, not including the height. What I mean is, if I set the height to 100% it makes the borders bigger on the input than on the button. This wouldn't be a problem if the button had borders. It does not (because it is an image). So to fix it in firefox I have to give it a set height of 20 (2 less than it should be, to compensate for the borders). No idea how to fix it more.

Comment: hmmm - it seems like you could make that button without an image with CSS and an icon "plus." You can't put block elements in the button, but do you have the image set to 100% height? Mystery.

Comment: I ditched the image and went with an `a` element, used inline-block and vertical-align bottom, then used border-radius (so ie9+ and others look good, ie8 is square, but lined up). That seemed to fix it in all browsers, except for ie7, but since ie8 works I'm not bothered.

Comment: If it's just the one little issue, you can use a conditional hack in your head for IE 6 and 7 and then just add a little margin 1px somewhere or something maybe.

Comment: I like to avoid those conditional hacks, but I might use it. I'm not terribly concerned about it being off by 1 in ie7.

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't really worry too much about IE 6 or 7 as long as it's still functional. If you are using IE 7 2013, you probably aren't a sticker for things working properly. Let us see it when you are done.

Comment: For modern day Safari, I had to set `margin: 0` for the button too. Regardless thank you!

Comment: So, you're saying, that safari's (only safari's) browser user-agent styles - add a margin to buttons?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using the bootstrap libraries.  See "Prepended and appended inputs" [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms).  They do a great job with browser compatibility.  You can further refine the l&f, so that it better matches what you have in your examples.

Comment: For this one thing I'd like to avoid using any libraries. I'm not even sure how that link helps me.

Comment: Fair enough if you don't want external libraries, but if you search down in that page for "Prepended and appended inputs", you will see examples of text fields with aligned buttons before and after them.

Comment: If that is what you want, take a look at the css they use and rip it out for your own use. (since they have already done the cross-browswer testing for you)

Comment: I see that. That is what i want, but I'm not sure where to begin in the CSS, there is a lot going on with that append. However, what I can gather, they are using a block with the rounded borders, I have seen that on some other sites. I'll have to experiment more with what I have. +1 for the link and advice.

Comment: If you're giving +1's for advice - I suggest using HTML and CSS AHAHAHAHAA!

Comment: I'll clarify. Constructive advice. Also, you need a link ;)